# Database suited most for handling 100MB to GB's

Tags: sql-server, oracle, tree, search-engine, information-retrieval

I have a requirement for storing 100MB to 1Gb of data (Strings like BOOK1, BOOK2..) and it grows. WhenEver user query for book1(by name) first name search is done (and it should be fast )and once match found it retrieves data associated to book1 like name of author, date of publication, edition etc.

1GB of data is just for the name of the books, but data related to books is more(author name, editions, printed date etc). So if i am just considering the 1GB(will grow) as indexing will Oracle or any SQL database will be fast and efficient for text search(search is only name of book, no scan of book).

[I thought of building index using suffix tree, but it uses 40 times * no of characters which is huge.]

Is Oracle or MS Sql or MySQL good choice for it?or do i need to think of Hadoop MapReduce or destributed computing.

Is there any bench marks for Oracle or other SQLs about accestime and number of concurrent access?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

According to your storage requirements you can use Oracle XE with following restrictions:

1. It will allow you to store up to 4G of data
2. Use up to 1G of RAM

Moreover it's free to use. You can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

1 GB of data can be handled by any DB you mentioned it considered small

Comment: 1GB of data is just for the name of the books, but data related to books is more(author name, editions, printed date etc). So if i am just considering the 1GB(will grow) as indexing will Oracle or any SQL database will be fast and efficient for text search(search is only name of book, no scan of book).

Comment: Most of the queries will be fast, but queries that search from beginning of the string like '%ame' can be very slow because regular indexes will not cover it, you need to utilize FULL TEXT search capabilities for such queries to be effective

Comment: Yes you are correct and i read Oracle supports Full text search but i could not get any info regarding its bench marks figures. Will Oracle do the job here or i have to go mapReduce way?

Comment: 1 GB is very conservative amount of data , to take it into perspective your average notebook now have 2GB-4GB of memory, even small server will have at least as much memory and probably 2-4 times as much. It can entirely fit into memory of a server. MapReduce make sense when you move into domains of hundreds of GBs of data.